# How to set default printer settings without driver

Tags: networking, printing, color-management

I am not at all an expert Linux user, but I do network and applications support for an office technology company.

One of our clients is a pharmacy which prints prescription labels through software called `RX30`. This software sits on a Linux server, and after a recent firmware update on the Konica Minolta bizhub printer which we service for them, the machine began counting the black and white RX labels as color.

Unfortunately, we are not able to downgrade the firmware.  I spoke with the support team at RX30, and they told me that they print via raw data dump over port 9100, and do not even use a driver.

My question is this: is there a place in the Linux OS where I can set a "default" for this hardware **without** installing a driver?

Comment: Are they using the CUPS system? http://www.cups.org/

Comment: "print via raw data dump to port 9100" suggests not.

Comment: Could you clarify the data flow? Do you mean that there is a program running on the Linux server, and it prints by connecting to the printer on port 9100, or is there a third machine involved? What are the precise symptoms of the problem (what do you mean by “counting the black and white RX labels as color”)? Since the problem since to be with the printer firmware and you can't change the printer firmware, do you know how to work around the problem from the printing software (if printing used a driver, would you know at least in principle what to do)?

Answer (score 1):

No, if it's connecting directly to the printer, you cannot set "defaults" unless the program that is making the connection has some way to do so.  (This is not OS-dependent.)  You would need to do something much more complex, such as using `iptables` to intercept the connection and redirect it to a program which filtered the data.